# I need to find $Emax_{t \in [T, 2T]} |W_{t}|$

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, expected-value

$W_{t}$ is a Wiener process.

I've spent a couple hours trying to solve that. I thought that Bachelier theorem can be applied here, but I'm not sure how exactly. Or maybe some other technique is at use here.

Maybe there is some martingale and stopping moment here, so I can use Dub's theorem.

Bachelier theorem: $\forall$ T and $x \geq 0$
$P (max W(t) \geq x) = 2P(W(T) \geq x)=P(|W(T)|\geq x)$.

Comment: I would be surprised that you can compute it, because you would need the joint distribution of $(\inf_t W_t, \sup_tW_t)$, what we don't know. But you can approximate it...

Comment: Why double-post your [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3821970/36150)? This is not going to do you any good...